# Conflict with animation. Elements with animation fade after open up the longlistselector again

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, animation, windows-phone-8

```
<phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-22,0" ItemsSource="{Binding CardItems}" Name="cardsList" SelectionChanged="cardsList_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>                            
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,2,0,4" Height="220">                             
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="cardBack" Height="200" Width="300" Visibility="{Binding visualBackSide, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <Image Source="/Assets/BackCard.png"/>
                                    <TextBox Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="140" Width="250" Text="{Binding CardFrontSide, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                    <Grid.Projection>
                                        <PlaneProjection/>
                                    </Grid.Projection>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="cardFront" Height="200" Width="300" Visibility="{Binding visualFrontSide, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <Image Source="/Assets/FrontCard.png"/>
                                    <TextBox Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="170" Width="280" Text="{Binding CardBackSide, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                    <Grid.Projection>
                                        <PlaneProjection/>
                                    </Grid.Projection>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <Storyboard x:Name="flipTo" >
                                        <PointAnimation Duration="0:0:2" To="0.5,0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardBack" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardBack" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardFront">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="-90"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardFront">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardBack">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    <Storyboard x:Name="flipFrom">
                                        <PointAnimation Duration="0:0:2" To="0.5,0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardFront" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardFront" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardBack">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="-90"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardBack">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardFront">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </Grid.Resources>
                            </Grid>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Button toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" BorderThickness="0" Click="DeleteCard_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonPressedTransparent}">
                                    <Image Source="/Assets/AppBarButtons/delete.png"/>
                                </Button>
                                <Button toolkit:TiltEffect.SuppressTilt="True" BorderThickness="0" Click="FlipCard_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonPressedTransparent}">
                                    <Image Source="/Assets/AppBarButtons/refresh.png"/>
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </StackPanel>                                                           
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <phone:LongListSelector.ListFooterTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Add new card" Width="200" Click="AddNewCard_Click"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ListFooterTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

So, here's the animation that turns over the grid with image and the textbox on it.

Code behind

```
private void FlipCard_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var temp = sender as Button;
    StackPanel stp = (StackPanel)temp.Parent;
    StackPanel stp1 = (StackPanel)stp.Parent;
    Grid all = (Grid)stp1.Children[0];
    Grid cardBack = (Grid)all.Children[0];
    Grid cardFront = (Grid)all.Children[1];

    if (cardBack.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        Storyboard sb = all.Resources["flipTo"] as Storyboard;
        sb.Begin();
        cardBack.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        cardFront.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        Storyboard sb = all.Resources["flipFrom"] as Storyboard;
        sb.Begin();
        cardBack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        cardFront.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

But whenever I rotate two elements (or more (I use two elements while testing)) to different sides, I face the next problem: When the longlistselector opens up again, objects vanish from the screen. I set visibility correctly for all the objects though. Objects may vanish both as well as one , even if I don't touch the object, the same picture comes up when I add a new object: If I've turned over the previous one, the next one appears empty, like visibility property for both grids is set 'collapsed'. It's not, though.

I'm sorry, but i cant post images yet.